# Which functions are the write/read interface for the linux bsg driver

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am not a driver writer and have a question about what functions are actually called within the bsg driver when one does a write(2)/read(2) from user-land.  My CentOS system is using Linux 2.6.32.  Surprisingly, though I have the sources for the build used by this CentOS system installed, the bsg.c file **isn't** there (huh?).  So, I downloaded from kernel.org the 2.6.32 sources.

I'm looking in *.../linux-2.6.32.61/block/bsg.c*.  For that source version, my question, is this function (on line 661) called when I call write(2) from user land?

```
static ssize_t
bsg_write(struct file *file, const char __user *buf, size_t count, loff_t *ppos)
```

I'm trying to track down why I'm getting EINVAL when calling write(2) in some cases but not in others when attempting to get SCSI Log Sense data.  If I'm on the right track in the driver sources, the *only* time that EINVAL is returned to the caller is the size of the data being written to the descriptor is not evenly divisible by `sizeof(sg_io_v4)` (defined in /usr/include/linux/bsg.h).

Andy

Comment: It's not a direct execution path from your userland `write()` to `bsg_write()`. There could be parameter checking in the C library and/or in the block device subsystem (that uses the fops vector) that could also return an EINVAL.  Also which filesystems are involved?

Comment: This is interesting to me.  How would I trace this path?  If I understand your question correctly, filesystems aren't involved here.  I'm opening a handle to /dev/bsg/w:x:y:z and performing SCSI commands through the write()/read() interface of the BSG driver.

Comment: *"How would I trace this path?"*  -- There's the kernel debugger.  Or cause a panic in your `bsg_write()` is a crude alternative (if you can tolerate possible corruption of mounted filesystems).  *"filesystems aren't involved here"* -- At the very least *devfs* is involved.  Look at the answer you accepted: the structure name is `file_operations`.  It's "file" not "device" operations.

Comment: @sawdust I am looking into building my own kernel for debugging purposes now.  Knowing which options to pick for the output I need is proving a bit tricky.

Comment: If you're referring to the kernel configuration, then you should first look for the `.config` file for the kernel you are already using as a starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is the right function. In the same file you can find this `static const struct file_operations bsg_fops` which is the definition of the function to use when userspace does something with the device

Comment: Thank you for that pointer to the bsg_fops structure.  As I stated, I'm not a driver writer (yet anyway).  I figured something like this needed to be in place.  After all, these functions aren't "magically" called: something must arrange it.

Comment: You search in the kernel source for the `file_operations` structures and how it uses them. Somewhere in the driver this set of operations is assigned to the block device, here you can see how the kernel take track of all `file_operations`, I think that is a good point where start